# How can I format a table in an InternetExplorer object?

Tags: html, css, vbscript

I'm looking for some help with the output formatting of this script that I wrote. The script works but my question is about the output results.

With this script I have it grabbing data from AD and outputting the results in a `objIE` form. I did this so the information can look neat. My question is how can you code the HTML into the VBScript (Not VBS into HTML). Below there is a picture of what the results look like but am not sure how I can do style editing (picture below).

Here's my code:

```
Call FindPCsThatUserLoggedInto

Sub FindPCsThatUserLoggedInto()
  'Get name to search for
  strUser = InputBox("Please Enter User's First Name")

  If strUser <> "" Then
    strLast = InputBox("Please Enter User's Last Name")

    If strLast <> "" Then
      'Set location parameter
      strLocation = ("Location")

      'Set AD Constant
      Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

      'Create objects
      Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

      'Open Active Directory
      objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
      objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

      'Set Active Directory connection object
      Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

      ' Set AD Command properties
      objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
      objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

      'Begin building HTML string headers
      s = "<table style = ""width:100%"" border = ""1""><tr><th>Name:</th><th>Username:</th><th>Location:</th><th>Employee ID:</th><th>Contractor ID:</th><th>Badge ID:</th></tr>"

      'Issue AD command
      objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ADSPath FROM 'LDAP://dc=,dc=,dc=com' WHERE givenName = '" & strUser & "*' AND sn = '" & strLast & "*' And physicalDeliveryOfficeName = '" & strLocation & "'"

      'Set RecordSet object to results
      Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

      'Make sure there are records returned
      If objRecordSet.Recordcount > 0 Then
        'Point to first record
        objRecordSet.MoveFirst

        'Loop through all records
        Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
          'Set user object
          Set objUser = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("ADSPath").Value)

          'Create temporary user string of the user name reversed twice
          strUser = strReverse(objUser.samaccountname) & strReverse(objUser.samaccountname)

          'Create temporary badge # reversed twice
          strBadge = strReverse(objUser.BadgeID) & strReverse(objUser.BadgeID)

          'Create TEMPID interlacing the first 5 characters of the two temp strings
          strTEMPID = MID(strUser,1,1)&MID(strBadge,1,1)&MID(strUser,2,1)&MID(strBadge,2,1)&MID(strUser,3,1)&MID(strBadge,3,1)&MID(strUser,4,1)&MID(strBadge,4,1)&MID(strUser,5,1)&MID(strBadge,5,1)

          'Populate HTML table with results
          s = s & "<tr><td>" & objUser.DisplayName & "</td><td>" & objUser.samaccountname & "</td><td>" & objUser.physicalDeliveryOfficeName & "</td><td>" & objUser.EmployeeNumber & "</td><td>" & objUser.ContractorID & "</td><td>" & objUser.BadgeID & "</td><td>" 

          'Move to next record
          objRecordSet.MoveNext
        Loop

        'Finish HTML string
        s = s & "</table>"

        'Create IE object and assign our HTML string to the body
        Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objIE.Navigate("about:blank")
        objIE.ToolBar = 0
        objIE.StatusBar = 0
        Set objDoc = objIE.Document.Body
        objDoc.InnerHTML = s
        objIE.Visible = True
      Else
        'Inform user of no records
        MsgBox "No users matching that criteria exist in AD."
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

The results look like:

[image: actual format]

Here is what I would like the output to look like:

[image: desired format]

I know the HTML code to create this - I am just not sure where to put the HTML code in the VBScript to make it output this.

Comment: Well change where you build the table; `s = "<table style = `

Comment: Where would I change it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally do this kind of formatting via [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) in HTML. With `InternetExplorer.Application` objects you can define a stylesheet like this:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
...

Set css = objIE.Document.CreateStyleSheet
css.AddRule "table", "border: 1px solid lightgray; border-collapse: collapse;"
css.AddRule "th", "color: black; background-color: white; font-weight: bold;"
css.AddRule "th, td", "border: 1px solid lightgray;"
css.AddRule "tr:nth-child(odd)", "background-color: lightgray;"
css.AddRule "tr:nth-child(even)", "background-color: white;"

...
```

The `:nth-child` pseudo-class allows you to alternate the row color between even and odd rows.

Comment: This works great! Would you do the same to change the layout of the body? 
For Example:
css.AddRule "body", "background:red;"

Comment: I ran into an issue with this code - everywith works well on my computer but when another person tries to run the script, they get all the information but get an error box that comes up saying 
(Line 88
Char 1
Invalid Argument)

Comment: @swstrau118 Please post a new question and include the relevant code, including the statement that raises the error.